# Unable to connect Cassandra Test Cluster

Tags: cassandra

I have created 1 node Cassandra cluster (datastax enterprise) on Ubuntu, to which I am able to connect via cqlsh but when i try to connect via OpsCenter or from VS2012 via c# driver I get error like "Unable to connect to cluster" or "All host tried for query are in error", can anyone help me with this error?

EDIT:

I installed the datastax Enterprise following the instructions as given at "datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/…; and have all keys with their default value in yaml file except the cluster name. When I run cqlsh it connect with this message:

```
Connected to fptestcluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6.28 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

But as specified in original question, with OpsCenter and C# driver I am not able to connect.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive? Possibly describing how you configured the cluster?

Comment: I installed the datastax Enterprise following the instructions as given at "http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html" and have all keys with their default value in yaml file except the cluster name. When I run cqlsh it connect with this message "Connected to fptestcluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6.28 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]" but as specified in original question with OpsCenter and C# driver I am not able to connect.

Comment: The port which use opscenter and the driver is different from the one that use cqlsh (thrift interface). For example you can check if the port for the native interface, the one that use the driver, (9042) is accesible.

Comment: In your `cassandra.yaml` what is your `listen_address` set to?

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for this, I had to change "listen_address" and "rpc_address" to the IP of machine rather than localhost and then it works, thanks everyone.

Comment: This is without a doubt the most-common solution to the "I can't connect to my Cassandra cluster" problem.

Comment: @user3582861 you might want to "accept" your own answer so this question will show as resolved (for the benefit of later readers)

Comment: If you want to be able to share the `cassandra.yaml` file then you should leave those two fields blank, and just use `cqlsh` with the IP address of your node i.e. `cqlsh 1.2.3.4`.